# How to set up parameters/filters for multi level filtering in tableau?

Tags: filter, tableau-api

I am new to tableau and in learning phase. I have a requirement for which i could not find any better answer. So thought of asking help from the experts here. Below is the requirement.

I have to build up a Actual Vs Target report. The table of actual and target are not related to each other. So i have made tables in two different workbooks which bring actual details from "Actual Workbook" and target details from "Target Workbook" and imported actual workbook into target workbook so that i can bring both worksheet in one dashboard.

Now comes the challenge. There are columns such as "Brand" , "Mrc" and "Prod Location" in both tables. But then there is something called "Target type" in the target table. So when i select only brand the data should be filtered for the target type "1" along with the selected brand from both actual and target reports.When i select brand and prod location, it has to be filtered with target type as "3" along with selected brand and prod location. If i select, brand, prod loc and mrc from the filters  it has to be filtered with target type as "4" along with selected brand,mrc and prod location and so on. It has affect both Actual and target reports whenever the filter is made though the tables are not joined or related to each other.

I tried to achieve this using parameters. But then, it is accepting only boolean values and didnt work out in my case.

Can anyone help me out to achieve this with step by step process (if possible) so that i can show some progress in my demo which is supposed to be today evening or tomorrow.

Thanks in Advance !!

-Aish

Comment: DId the answer solve your query ?

Answer (score 0):

I did not completely understand the data you have, I will try to explain using an example from my end.

Consider, 2 Data sources on tableau end,

Data source A -> has category A and count , etc.

Data source B -> has category B and sum , etc.

Now I Create a parameter called select category and put all categories in that parameter.

Now I go to sheet1 which is created on Data Source A, create a calculated field, which will say `[category A] = [select category]`

Drag this on the filter for sheet1 and set value to `true`

Now I go to sheet2 which is created on Data Source A, create a calculated field, which will say `[category b] = [select category]`

Drag this on the filter for sheet2 and set value to `true`

Now create your dashboard, click on show parameter, and check if parameter selection changes the data for both the sheets. (Keep single value parameter).